# Sufficient criterion for convergence of infinite sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Assume it holds that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k=0$ where $a_k$ is a number in (0,1) for every $k\geq 1$. Besides that nothing is known.

Now I wonder whether it is correct that

$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^na_k$

is converging, i.e. the limit is not $\infty$.

My approach was to extend the sequence to some differentiable function and then to apply L'Hopital but I'm not sure that's the way go or whether the statement is correct.

Comment: You cannot, and the simplest counterexample is the harmonic series (i.e. $a_k=1/k$).

Comment: Thanks! This answers the question.

Comment: By the way your approach doesn't require an extension to a continuous function. The Stolz-Cesaro theorem is the analog of L'Hopital for sequences.  In this case with $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{S_n}{n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{S_n - S_{n-1}}{n - (n-1)} = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$. when the limit exists. Thus if $a_n \to a$ then $S_n/n \to a$.  Unfortunately the converse is not always true and in any case does not help with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Consider the terms $a_k = 1/k$ where $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k = \mathcal{O}(\log n)$

Comment: Thanks! This answers the question.

Comment: @AlexanderJI  You're welcome.